# I want to validate two columns together wrt uniqueness

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Validate uniqueness of two columns in Laravel.

controller

```
function insert(Request $request)
    {       
    $this->validate($request, [
     'School_name' =>  'required',
     'class'       =>  'required',
     'Address'     =>  'required|composite_unique:School_name,Address',
     'Country'     =>  'required',
     'State'       =>  'required',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming your table name is `schools`

```
function insert(Request $request)
{       
    $this->validate($request, [
        'School_name' =>  'required',
        'class'       =>  'required',
        'Address'     =>  'required|unique:schools,School_name,NULL,id,Address,'.$request->School_name,
        'Country'     =>  'required',
        'State'       =>  'required',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First install the package through Composer or cmd:

```
composer require felixkiss/uniquewith-validator
```

Add the following to your providers array in config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
// ...

Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\ServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Then in Controller :

```
  function insert(Request $request)
            {       
                $this->validate($request, [
        'School_name'         =>  'required',
        'class'             =>  'required',
        'Address'            =>'required|unique_with:school,Address,School_name',
        'Country'             =>  'required',
        'State'               =>  'required',
                ]);
```